# How to modify matrix in raku-lang

Tags: raku

When I try to modify matrix in raku. 
I got the error :

```
my @matrix = ^100 .rotor(10);
@matrix[1;*] = 1 xx 10
Cannot modify an immutable Int (10)
      in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
@matrix[1;1] = 3
Cannot modify an immutable List ((10 11 12 13 14 15 1...)
      in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Why all of those values are immutable value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [lists](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#Immutability) are always immutable. You can modify their container, but not themselves. [`rotor`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor) creates lists, so once they have been created, you can't modify them.
Don't know exactly what you want to do here, but looking at the errors here, I would say you need to turn those immutable lists into mutable `Array`s:

```
my @matrix = ^100 .rotor(10).map: *.Array;
@matrix[1;*] = 1 xx 10;
@matrix[1;1] = 3;
```